# Backup a vmware machine daily and eventually restore it in hyper-v

Tags: vmware-esxi, hyper-v, windows-server-2019

I have a vmware ESXI with 4 vm inside, in the same facility I have a Windows 2019 standard server big enough to host the vm and the backup. Can I have a daily backup from vmware esxi inside the windows server, and eventually restore it in hyper-v inside that server? If I can, how can I do it? What Tools do I need?

Comment: Of course you can. Product recommendations are off topic though, so I'm voting to close the question.

Comment: so you say i have to use a third party backup tool? or i can do it with microsoft native tools?

Comment: Microsoft does not have any tools that could backup ESXi VMs. So yes, third party tools.

Comment: and then convert that backup with Microsoft Virtual Machine Converter 3.0?

Comment: Microsoft Converter is trash and discontinued product. It should be avoided. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/system-center-blog/microsoft-virtual-machine-converter-mvmc-is-being-retired/ba-p/351541

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, backup with Veeam (or any other backup application you’re familiar with) and restore to the new location. Apply StarWind V2V Converter to change VM format. You can PowerShell script both CLI versions easily.

Comment: is it possible to use starwind v2v conferter on the backup without restoring it? thank you for the answer.

Comment: I don’t think they support vbk format, but you’d better ask directly.